# Niederlassungserlaubnis card has expiry date

Tags: germany, resident-permit

So I received my Niederlassungserlaubnis in June 2020 and I noticed that it has an expiry date until my passport (Pakistani) expires. Is this normal ? I assumed that Niederlassungserlaubnis is not time limited. What happens on expirr ?

Comment: The same thing you do before your passport expires, apply for a new one. Once you have a new passport, you apply for a new card - that then will be valid until your new passport expires.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Comment: I have a same situation. I have to wait for 4 months for new card, after expiry of old card.. so is it valod with new passport
how did you face this time? have got any trouble or solution? can I travel to other countries in EU in that 4 months time?

Answer (score 3):

In Germany (other countries do this differently) the validity of the **residence card** is based on one of the two following conditions:

- how long you are allowed to remain
- how long your passport is valid for

whatever is shorter.

As long as you still fullfill all conditions, the **Niederlassungserlaubnis** is not time limited.

Before your passport expires, you should apply for a new one in a timely mannor.

Once you have a new passport, you apply for a new card - that then will be valid until your new passport expires.